# MySQL: Cascade vs. Restrict

Tags: mysql, cascade

I'm working on a database and am using many foreign keys to connect my tables. By default, MySQL sets all of the `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` to `RESTRICT`. This seemed to work fine.

Then one time, I wanted to change the `id` of several of the rows in a table. This table was involved in many relationships, so I changed the relations to `CASCADE` so that the changes would be cascaded to the tables that used that `id` as a foreign key.

Now I think to myself, is there any reason to leave the relations as `RESTRICT`, since `CASCADE` seems to make my life easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you do want to implement all relations logic in your code. And you use `RESTRICT` just to control yourself - to see errors when you forgot some case.

Also keep in mind that `CASCADE`  operation are sometimes very unexpected, and with huge codebase you should always keep it in mind. So it can be a good solution not to use them at all - helps to organise design of your application, BTW.

Another approach - sometimes you do have circular relations (for example with denormalisation) and `CASCADE` is impossible to use.

Answer (score 1):

Changing IDs should be a pretty rare thing.  Resist the temptation to remove gaps or keep your IDs "tidy," if that was your motivation.  If it was, then the answer is easy.  No, don't. :)  It's generally important, particularly in more complex systems, that an ID in a given domain never represents more than different "thing," ever, even separated by time.  Note how if you insert a row into a auto-increment table, then roll back the insert, the id isn't reused, even if there were no other competing actions.

If an id is an auto-increment or any other kind of surrogate key, it's rare that there would be a legitimate reason to change it, and cascading updates are more likely to fire only in response to an error made by you or the code... not for an intentional change.

Cascading updates should generally only be considered for natural keys, where there's a possibility that the parent table's primary key might actually need to be updated.

Natural keys are ids that come from the real world, like a vehicle's VIN or the tax authority assigned parcel number of a piece of real estate, seen as primary keys more frequently in theory than in actual practice... while surrogate keys have zero meaning outside the database (and thus should not be exposed to the user), such as auto increments and internally-generated GUIDs.

Cascading deletes are legitimately used where deleting the parent is to be expected in the normal course of events and the sudden disappearance of all the child rows is also desirable.

As a rule, though, if in doubt, `RESTRICT` is always the safest course.